# Clear first item displayed in ASP.Net Core select tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a asp select tag in my razor form:

```
<div class="form-group row" style="align-items:center">
     <label class="col-form-label" style="padding-left:14px; width: 100px">Client:</label>
     <select name="ClientsSelect" asp-for="@Model.SelectedClient" class="form-control" style="width: 300px" asp-items="@Model.Clients">
          <option value="" disabled>-- Select Client --</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Then in my code behind, I populate the list:

```
public SelectList Clients { get; set; }
public string SelectedClient { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{           
    var clientList = new string[]{"Client 1", "Client 2"};
    Clients = new SelectList(clientList, "");          

    return Page();
}
```

When Client list gets displayed, the first item in the SelectList (i.e., "Client 1") is displayed even though the `selectedValue` is set to `""` in the SelectList. How can I remove the first item in the SelectList from being selected?

Comment: Remove the `disabled` attribute from the empty option.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping not to removing that attribute or to have the select display an empty or null selection. But if that is not possible, your suggestion works.

Comment: Is `Model.SelectedClient == ""` (or null, or not in the items)?

Comment: Model.SelectedClient is null.

Comment: Hi @tval, any update here?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, just change your PageModel like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var clientList = new string[] { "","Client 1", "Client 2" };  //change here...
    Clients = new SelectList(clientList, "");
       
    return Page();
}
```

Remove the option in page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<div class="form-group row" style="align-items:center">
    <label class="col-form-label" style="padding-left:14px; width: 100px">Client:</label>
    <select name="ClientsSelect" asp-for="@Model.SelectedClient" class="form-control" style="width: 300px" asp-items="@Model.Clients">
        @*<option value=null >-- Select Client --</option>*@  //remove here...
    </select>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]